# How to Align 3 Views Horizontal in LinearLayout or other Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align 3 Views in horizontally in Single Row a `CheckBox`, an `EditText` and an `ImageButton`. I tried My Best But dint able to implement properly I have pasted XML code below please give some advice or sample code Please Help me Thanks in Advance

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:padding="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/parentLinear">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="37dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_blue" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/add_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...!!! It Helped Me and All of the Above Code's are Working but your sample code is Perfect for my Requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Linear layout it would be better if you use either RELATIVE LAYOUT or Constraint Layout(better) . It would be easier to make and will perform better. 
or
Use a single linear Layout to align the views and you are using too many linear layouts which will be a very costly operation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<EditText
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"/>

<ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to use nested layout for this

You can achieve it using only single `LinearLayout`

You can set `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_fav"` in your `EditText` to replace you image button

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_fav"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> Another way

if you don't want to use `android:drawableEnd` than here is second solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="37dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fav" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> drawable/test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#3498db"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: and what about 3rd View? How to place third view here i am struggling

Comment: @Rakesh which third view

Comment: ImageButton check in Screenshot

Comment: @Rakesh i have added `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_fav"` in  so need to use another `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

For `LinearLayout` you have to use `android:orientation="horizontal"`. For `ConstraintLayout` you have to use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="value like 1, 2"`  and for this you have to set `RightToLeftOf` and `LegtToRightOf` for both views. For `RelativeLayout` Your have to set `alignSTartToEndOf` in your child view

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need nested `LinearLayout`. One `LinearLayout` is enough to achieve your requirement. Try to the following code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkBox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:text="Name"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
      android:layout_width="37dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try to use less layout as possible as you can.